# QPushButton click event inside a QStackWidget is sent to parent window

Tags: qt

I have a MainWindow class and within it a QStackWidget.
Inside it I have another 3 widgets, each one is my own custom class derived from QWidget.

Inside one of the widgets I have a button.

When I am using QT Creator and press `Go to slot..` on the button, it creates an `on_button_clicked` event in MainWindow class.

How do I change it to have the event inside my custom class?

UPDATE:
I can see that the buttons are located in MainWindow. This is auto generated, so I am not sure how to move it.

Code:
mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include  "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Button 2 clicked!", "Click");
}
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>668</width>
    <height>630</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>531</width>
      <height>391</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>1</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="Stack1" name="page">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>140</x>
        <y>110</y>
        <width>321</width>
        <height>121</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Button on Stack1</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="Stack2" name="page_2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>110</x>
        <y>140</y>
        <width>371</width>
        <height>161</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Button on stack2</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>668</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>Stack1</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>stack1.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
  <customwidget>
   <class>Stack2</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>stack2.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I want the button callback to be inside my custom class stack2.cpp

```
#include "stack2.h"

Stack2::Stack2(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}

Stack2::~Stack2()
{

}
```

Comment: You can just move created slot to your class. As long as the widget has a child named `button`, the slot will work. Qt Designer sometimes places new slots in weird places for some reasons. Do you use "go to slot" in the editor of the corresponding form class?

Comment: I tried to move the function manually and it still doesn't work. Furthermore, I created 2 buttons. One with the slot on the main page, and the second with the slot in the stackedwidget, and only the one on the main page is working.

Comment: You made promotion correctly but you should not fill contents of promoted widgets in main window form (i.e. put buttons in them). Instead, create stack page classes as Designer Form Classes (just as `MainWindow` but based on `QWidget`) and put contents in them using separate form editor.  Alternatively, you can add layouts and buttons to stack pages manually in their constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made promotion correctly but you should not fill contents of promoted widgets in main window form (i.e. put buttons in them). Instead, create stack page classes as Designer Form Classes (just as `MainWindow` but based on `QWidget`) and put contents in them using separate form editor. Alternatively, you can add layouts and buttons to stack pages manually in their constructors.